# TimThumb and 777 permissions

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, timthumb

I have TimThumb running on a Wordpress site and the only way I can get it to work is with the timthumb directory permissions set to 777. I don't like doing this though, where I've had to use 777 permissions before I've put a .htaccess file in the directory to stop scripts running inside that directory, obviously won't be able to do this inside the timthumb directory. Does anyone know a way of allowing timthumb to work without having to use 777?

Answer (score 1):

TimThumb requires write access to a particular folder
*(I can't recall which one right now but I'm looking it up)*

You don't have to 777 the whole directory, just that particular folder

Also, I believe 660 may be adequete for this folder (Read / Write)

It's also worth looking at this:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/timthumb-vulnerability-scanner/

There was an exploit on a previous version of TimThumb, that this plugin aims to scan for.